# My Code In Pythin 3.4.4 WOrked But Now Its Saying Idex Is Out Of Range

Tags: python

This is The Code I've Created And It Usually Works But For Some Reason It Started Saying

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "\\vfs\pupil$\2015\15fosterh\NEA 2019\Code\Code.py", line 75, in <module>
> answer = linelist[1]
> IndexError: list index out of range''
> ```

```
Welcome To The Quiz
You must Properly Capatalize
If the puncuation is not shown in a question
It doesnt need to be capataziled
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000000043AECA8>
W______ M_ By Hasley
 Enter your answer here:
```

this is the code

```
  if selection in C:
      print("Welcome To The Quiz")
      print("You must Properly Capatalize")
      print("If the puncuation is not shown in a question")
      print("It doesnt need to be capataziled")
      score = 0
      b=[]
      filedata_list = []
      track = tuple(random.randint(0,20)for number in('songs.txt'))
      #print(track)
      datalist = (line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('songs.txt'))
      for row in datalist:
          linelist = row.split(',')
          question = linelist[0]
          #print(question)
           answer = linelist[1]
          #print(answer)
          number = linelist[2]
          #print(number)
          b = (question,answer,number)
           filedata_list.append(b)
      for line in filedata_list:
          print(line[1])
          response = input("Enter your answer here: ")
          if response == line[1]:
              score = score + 3
              print("Correct!")
           else:
                  print("WRONG!One more try")
                  response = input("Enter your answer here: ")
          if response == line[1]:
              score = score + 1   
              print("Good job! You scored: " + str(score))
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sounds like a little check is in order here, something like: `if linelist:` or `if len(linelist) > 0`(in case you like things to be explicit); just before the line that threw you the error.

Comment: please format the error that you are getting

Comment: Do a `print(len(linelist))` after the line `linelist = row.split(',')` to see how many items in your list. There are only **1** item in the list!